# Starting ssh-agent on Windows 10 fails: "unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058"

Tags: ssh, service, windows-10, openssh

When I try to start the ssh-agent on Windows 10 via PowerShell (with elevated right or without) by entering `Start-Service ssh-agent` I get the error

> unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058

When I check of the service is running via `Get-Service ssh-agent` is returns that the service is stopped.

How can I get the ssh-agent running?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the StartupType of the ssh-agent to `Manual` via `Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Manual`.

Then I was able to start the service via `Start-Service ssh-agent` or just `ssh-agent.exe`.

Comment: I get the error `Set-Service` is not recognized as an internal or external command. What should I do in that case

Comment: By default the service is disabled in Windows 10. You need to set its startup type to manual as it work start while it's disabled.

Comment: @Code_Ninja
Use PowerShell instead of CMD

Comment: Please make sure to run the command with **Administrator** access

Answer (score 750):

Yeah, as others have suggested, this error seems to mean that ssh-agent is installed but its service (on windows) hasn't been started.

You can check this by running in Windows **PowerShell**:

```
> Get-Service ssh-agent
```

And then check the output of status is not running.

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

Then check that the service has been disabled by running

```
> Get-Service ssh-agent | Select StartType

StartType
---------
Disabled
```

I suggest setting the service to start manually. This means that as soon as you run ssh-agent, it'll start the service. You can do this through the Services GUI or you can run the command in **admin mode**:

```
 > Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
```

Alternatively, you can set it through the GUI if you prefer.

[image: services.msc showing the properties of the OpenSSH Agent]

Comment: I was receiving the error `Set-Service: Service 'OpenSSH Authentication Agent (ssh-agent)' cannot be configured due to the following error: Access is denied.`. There were no problems doing it via the GUI though.

Comment: I assume that means you weren't using an admin shell

Comment: Yes I wasn't using an admin shell.

Comment: After Windows 10 update 2004 this was reset to `disabled` and had to repeat these instructions.

Comment: I was getting "Access is denied" when trying to do "-StartType Manual" (probably due to it's a working laptop I don't know) but the GUI does the job. Thanks for sharing the extra tip!

Comment: for those wondering how to access the GUI, just: bring up the start menu  --> type Services  --> find the OpenSSH Authentication Agent service

Comment: It helped me. Did not know what is the problem, but it was because of the StartType disabled. Thanks!

Comment: `'Get-Service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Got this error in powershell

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan what's your powershell version? In powershell, type:

```$PSVersionTable```

Comment: This is the answer and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem follow only a few steps:

1 => open Window Powershell as administrator and write

2 => Get-Service ssh-agent  //(you will find status stopped )

3 => Now write in the Powershell

4 => Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Manual

you will find status running.. hopefully help to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I get the same error in **Cygwin**. I had to **install the openssh package in Cygwin Setup**.

(The strange thing was that all `ssh-*` commands were valid, (bash could execute as program) but the openssh package wasn't installed.)

Answer (score 6):

Adding here that if you have this problem and run `start-ssh-agent` in PowerShell it will "switch" to cmd(not powershell) like functionality until you `exit` the batch job started by your previous command.
If you don't, you can no longer access PowerShell functions and will get errors like: `'Get-Service' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This just happens to me because I was running the command in a non-administrator Powershell. Running it with admin powers solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the SSH agent started due to the executable itself being corrupt. The error I was getting was 1053, won't start in a timely manner.

This was in the event viewer log

```
Faulting application name: ssh-agent.exe, version: 8.6.0.1, time stamp: 0x624f4fc8
Faulting module name: ssh-agent.exe, version: 8.6.0.1, time stamp: 0x624f4fc8
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x0000000000020767
Faulting process id: 0x0x478C
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DA69733420E80B
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe
Report Id: e09f95af-119c-4e70-999b-f49fdaaf76cc
```

Who knows how this happened, but anyway it did.

To fix this, from an elevated powershell prompt:

- `Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0` to remove the client capability.
- `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` remove the locally cached executable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11)
- `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0` to add the client capability back in.