# git clone with SSH only working in Git Bash not on Windows CMD

Tags: bash, git, ssh, cmd, git-bash

So, I've followed [this](https://github.com/antonykidis/Setup-ssh-for-github/blob/master/Setup-ssh-on-github.pdf) tutorial on how to Setup SSH for github with Windows CMD and all was working fine until I went to clone a repo with

```
git clone git@github.com:{myusername}/{myrepo}.git
```

Where I get

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Even when I run `ssh -T git@github.com` I get the expected message telling me I'm authenticated.

After scratching my brain for a while, I decided to try it on git bash.

First thing I noticed was that running

```
 ssh-add -l
```

in git bash, I was getting `The agent has no identities.` but when I run the same command on Windows CMD I get all my SSH keys?

So, after adding my ssh key in git bash I was able to clone my repository.

So, why is it only on git bash I can do this and not on the cmd or powershell? Is it something to do with what seems like they are using different ssh agents? How can I sync them together if that is the case?

Furthermore, when I run the following command

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

with the cmd I get

```
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\{myuserdirectory}/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

but with git bash I get

```
debug1: identity file /c/Users/{myuserdirectory}/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
```

Another difference is that in windows cmd I don't get any instances of
`debug1: Will attempt key: ....`

When I exit git bash and open up another git bash terminal, running `ssh-add -l` again, it returns `The agent has no identities.` even after I added it before, it's like it only persists for each session, which also isn't desirable.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Probably you were right and they were using different ssh-agents. I had exactly the same problem and this answer helped me a lot:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720527/6486458

By default git refers to its own ssh in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`. I added `GIT_SSH` environment variable and set it to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`. This prevents inconsistency between the versions of ssh. After that git started to work as expected from both Git Bash and Windows cmd.

From git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables):

> `GIT_SSH`, if specified, is a program that is invoked instead of ssh
> when Git tries to connect to an SSH host. It is invoked like `$GIT_SSH [username@]host [-p <port>] <command>`.

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/6486458

Comment: Thank you, I have added GIT_SSH as window system env var and works!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ssh-agent is not running or not recognize your ssh key

try this:

```
# add the default ~/.ssh keys to the ssh-agent
ssh-add

# restart the ssh-agent
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

---

```
# On windows:
start-ssh-agent
```

---

#### `ssh-add`

> ssh-add adds RSA or DSA identities to the authentication agent, ssh-agent.
>   When run **without arguments**, it adds the files `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and `~/.ssh/identity`.
>
> Alternative file names can be given on the command line

Comment: That is what I was using for git bash, but I get `'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` in the cmd?

Comment: Execute it in git bash and try again the CMD. what is the result?

Comment: I have updated my answer for you for windows with `start-ssh-agent`

Comment: Tried running in bash and execting in the CMD with the same result. Also, running `start-ssh-agent` then `ssh-add -l` is returning `Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory`. I have no idea why?

Comment: No joy in powershell either, still get the same result when trying to clone a git repo...

Comment: In power shell (run as admin) execute this before:  `Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual`

Comment: Yeah, that's how I did it via Powershell to begin with https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606760/3113377, I'm really at a loss here, everything works right up until I clone a repo. Like, it even says I'm authorized? Anything to do with the extra backslashes in the directory references from running `ssh -Tv git@github.com`? No idea how they got there in the first place to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird bug on Windows if you install Git bash. Open Command prompt, and  do

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

if you find this folder already created, then copy the public and private key from your user folder to this path:

```
cp C:\Users\username\.ssh\id_* ~/.ssh/
```

For some reason, windows command prompt creates this path the first time you do a git clone, and after that it just requests for git@gitlab / git@github password.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to verify if your git client is using SSH or credential, for my case, credential is used by default.

So, try to run, (or omit the `--global` if you use a dedicated config for some certain repo)

```
git config --global --list
```

Make sure `core.sshcommand=C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe` is listed, otherwise add it by running

```
git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

Just a few more context, if your `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` command welcomed you, but you still get the denied error whenever `clone` or `pull` or `fetch`, most likely it is caused by git client not using SSH at all. If `ssh -T ...` failed, then SOF some ssh related topics