# Error connecting to agent: no such file or directory - adding key to ssh agent

Tags: ssh, cmd, bitbucket, ssh-keys, git-clone

I am trying to add key that I have generated to the ssh agent. Below are my steps

```
C:\repo>ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\mante1/.ssh/id_rsa):C:\repo\key
```

After the key is generated, I am starting the ssh agent and adding it

```
C:\repo>start-ssh-agent
Found ssh-agent at 13460
Found ssh-agent socket at /tmp/ssh-vKzdrs37QYVK/agent.821

C:\repo>ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to manually start ssh-agent service first [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113738/starting-ssh-agent-on-windows-10-fails-unable-to-start-ssh-agent-service-erro)

Answer (score 37):

- Start Windows PowerShell with Run as Administrator mode.
- Follow these commands there...

```
Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic

# By default the ssh-agent service is disabled. Configure it to start automatically.
# Make sure you're running as an Administrator.
```

```
Start-Service ssh-agent

# Start the service
```

```
Get-Service ssh-agent

# This should return a status of Running
```

```
ssh-add <complete-key-path-here>

Key Path Example: C:\Users\so\.ssh/key-name
# Now load your key files into ssh-agent
```

> Original Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

Answer (score 21):

This problem is maybe because you have two types of ssh-agent.exe , you can see them in task-manager , one ssh-agent will be from git and other one would be from OpenSSH.

**Fix**

1. End all ssh task from task-manager
2. Go to the directory where the key is in your case `C:\repo\key`  this should be your working directory and then run `start-ssh-agent` will automatically add your private key to the ssh and you won't need the `ssh-add` command .

**Imp**

1. `start-ssh-agent` will use the ssh from git
2. `start ssh-agent` will use the ssh from OpenSSH

So there can be inconsistencies between the version of ssh you're using and your keys are added/generated with

Comment: This fix did it for me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 20):

VonC is probably right, in that you need to fix your path, but I was facing the same problem *despite* using the correct one. In my case, I needed to **start ssh-agent for the command to work**.

Running the sample commands from GitHub was not working, but, since I had installed OpenSSH, I simply **started the pre-installed "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" service**, on the Services app, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40720527/1293116).

Answer (score 13):

If you have generated your key at `C:\repo\key`, then the key you need to `ssh-add` is... `C:\repo\key`, *not* `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

```
C:\repo>ssh-add C:\repo\key
```

That would work.

Answer (score 13):

Try to type:

```
ssh-agent bash
```

and then execute:

```
ssh-add...
```

Comment: for zsh it's ssh-agent zsh

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the `~` was the problem. Once I typed out my full path `ssh-add C:\Users\qa95\.ssh\id_rsa` it worked.

Looks like the tilde expansion to the user's directory is not fully supported in PowerShell, so even though `dir ~\.ssh\id_rsa` may work fine, `ssh-add` doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3):

This was also happening to me on Windows. I was able to fix this way:

1. For Windows, leave a blank passphrase when creating the ssh file
2. Make sure your HOMEPATH env is pointing to where the .ssh folder is saved

```
$env:HOMEPATH='C:\Users\<username>'
```

Answer (score -3):

It's also important to have it exactly in specific user directory in a folder name `'.ssh'` but the file names don't have to be `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: They actually do not have to be id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. For instance I have a corporate ssh key with that name, but my personal keys are named id_rsa_personal and id_rsa_personal.pub

Comment: I have updated answer with your infromation